# Related work for a 'compatibility' modality in modal logic meaning ◊(∧′)

Tags: reference-request, modal-logic, kripke-models

Fix some set of **propositional atoms** $\mathsf{Atoms}$ and consider a (very simple) propositional logic with a binary **compatibility** modality $\mathsf{C}$ as follows:
$$
\phi,\phi' ::= A,B,C\in\mathsf{Atoms} \mid \phi\lor\phi' \mid \mathsf{C}(\phi,\phi') .
$$

- $\mathsf{C}(\phi,\phi')$ is read as "$\phi$ and $\phi'$ are **compatible**".
- The intuition of $\mathsf{C}(\phi,\phi')$ is that $\phi$ and $\phi'$ might be true at the same time in some possible world (and so are "compatible").
- If the reader is familiar with modal possibility $\Diamond$, then we can think of $\mathsf{C}(\phi,\phi')$ as expressing $\Diamond(\phi\land\phi')$ (we do not need to include $\Diamond$ or $\land$ in the logic above).

This logic has intended semantics as follows:

- In *topological spaces*, write $[[-]]$ for the denotation.  Then propositional atoms denote open sets, $\lor$ denotes sets union, and $[[\mathsf{C}(\phi,\phi')]]$ is the whole space if $[[\phi]]$ and $[[\phi']]$ intersect, and is empty otherwise.
- In *Kripke models*, $w\vDash\mathsf{C}(\phi,\phi')$ --- in words: "$\mathsf{C}(\phi,\phi)$ is valid at world $w$" --- when there exists some future world $w\to w'$ such that $w'\vDash \phi$ and $w'\vDash \phi'$.

**Question:** Has a modality like $\mathsf{C}$ been studied, and if so, where?

Thank you.

Comment: If you don’t have negation, then $\mathsf C(\phi, \phi’)$ holds for any $\phi, \phi’$.